# Pandas dataframe concat function creates two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

When using the concat function on two panda dataframes, which each consists out of only one row, I end up with two rows.
These are the two dataframes I want to concat:

```
OptieA_Q14 = pd.DataFrame(['vliegtuig', 90, 120, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'omruiling', 'wifi na betaling']).transpose()

gegevens = pd.DataFrame(totaal.iloc[5,0:12]).transpose()
```

Where the second one is a part of a much bigger dataframe.

When using this line of code to concat the two:

```
  volledige_rij = pd.concat([gegevens, OptieA_Q27], axis=1)
```

The resulting dataframe consists out of two rows as you can see in the image.

[image]

I want this however to be a dataframe consisting out of 1 row and not filled up with NaN.

Comment: The problem is that both Dataframes have different column names. The algorithm is not able the put this together as it doesn't know which is which.

Comment: Do you mean that they have different types of column names (integer vs string)?

Comment: Exactly, integers as column names are interpreted as strings. For concat to work, both dataframes need exactly the same column captions. At least that is my understanding.